# Angular Tailwind CSS Arbitrary Values doesn't work locally

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwindcss version 3.x.x.I followed this tutorial : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular and I installed it

Here is my html code

```html
<div class="ml-[{{type.level * 10}}px]"></div>
```

It doesn't work, but when I use :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

It works. What is the problem?

Comment: Avoid using [dynamic](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) class names. Inline style may be a good solution in your case